# Ask $\bar{X}$ distribution in normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a $n(\theta,\sigma^2)$ population, $\sigma^2$ known. Then we know $(\bar{X}-\theta)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}) \sim n(0,1)$.

Does this property depends on $\sigma^2$ known or unknown? Is there any difference between $\sigma^2$ known or unknown?

The background is normal power function. (George Casella example 8.3.3). An LRT of $H_0:\theta \leq \theta_0$ versus $H_1:\theta > \theta_0$ is a test that rejects $H_0$ if $(\bar{X}-\theta_0)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}) >c$. Then we can show the power function of this test is $\beta(\theta)=P(Z>c+(\theta_0-\theta)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}))$, where Z is a standard normal random variable, since $(\bar{X}-\theta)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}) \sim n(0,1)$.

Then I ask my question. Since this question said $\sigma^2$ known. I am wondering whether Z is standard normal depends on $\sigma^2$ known or not.

Comment: Imprecise question. Maybe hinting at distinction between z-test when $\sigma$ known, and t test when not. // Please clarify what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: I edited. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Clearer now. Just waking up here; hope there are no typos in _my_ Answer. // z if $\sigma$ known; t if $\sigma$ estimated by $S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result does not depend on wheter $\sigma$ is known or not, but in practice, how can we even hope to calculate $\frac{\bar X-\theta}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}$, when $\sigma$ is unknown to us? A proper statistic should only rely on data and not on unknown parameters.

When $\sigma$ is unknown, the usual approach would be to replace $\sigma$ by the estimated standard deviation $S= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - \bar{X})^2}$ and create a new statistic $T=\frac{\bar X-\theta}{S/\sqrt{n}}$, however this new statistic does not have a normal distribution. It has a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you for excellent explanation. But I assume you mean x bar in your math expressions. Also, your S expression looks incorrect.

Comment: Fixed a couple of obvious typos.

Comment: @BruceET thank you. Yes, the edited version is what i initially meant.

Answer (score 1):

Consider data `x`, sample of size 10 from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = 7).$  [Sampling and computations in R.]

```
set.seed(409)
x = rnorm(10, 50, 7)
mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 52.72141
[1] 5.834154
```

(1) Suppose you know $\sigma = 7$ and want a 95% CI for $\mu.$ The formula for interval endpoints is $\bar X \pm 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{10}}.$ This is derived from
$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{10}} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ The CI is $(48.38, 57,06)$ of length
$8.68.$

```
CI = mean(x) + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*7/sqrt(10);  CI
[1] 48.38285 57.05998
diff(CI)
[1] 8.67713  # length
```

(2) Suppose you know neither $\mu$ nor $\sigma$ and want a 95% CI for $\mu.$
The formula for interval endpoints is $\bar X \pm t^* \frac{S}{\sqrt{10}},$ where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025$ from the upper tail of (symmetrical) Student's t distribution with $\nu = n-1 = 9$ degrees of freedom. This is derived from
$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{10}} \sim \mathsf{T}(9).$ The CI is $(48.54, 56,89)$ of length $8.35.$

**On average,** CIs based on Student's t
distribution are a little longer (thus less informative) than are CIs based on a standard normal distribution.
This is because knowing the exact value of $\sigma$ provides additional information. However, **in this example,**
the t CI happens to be shorter than the z CI, because
the estimate $S = 5.834$ of $\sigma = 7$ happens to be
a little too small.

```
CI = mean(x) + qt(c(.025,.975), 9)*sd(x)/sqrt(10); CI
[1] 48.54791 56.89491
diff(CI)
[1] 8.347004
```

Such confidence intervals are computed as part of the procedure `t.test` in R:

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 48.54791 56.89491
 attr(,"conf.level")
 [1] 0.95
```

*Note:* The following simulation of 100,000 samples of size 10 from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = 7)$ shows that the
average length of a t CI is about 9.75 compared with the fixed length 8.67713 of z CIs (based on samples of size 10 from a normal population with $\sigma=7).$

```
set.seed(2021)
d = replicate(10^5, 
diff(t.test(rnorm(10,50,7))$conf.int))
mean(d)
[1] 9.748929
```